# hubflow: what command should I do if I want to go from 0.0.1-rc2 to 0.0.1 on the master branch?

Tags: git, github, git-flow

I am currently learning the [HubFlow](http://datasift.github.com/gitflow/GitFlowForGitHub.html) way of managing versioning and workflow using Git and GitHub.

I created this [dummy repository](https://github.com/simkimsia/learnhubflow) to get some hands-on experience.

I have tried the following:

1. creating release branches from develop branch
2. closing the release branches
3. creating hotfix branches from master branch
4. closing hotfix branches

Now I have 0.0.1-rc2 on my master branch. The tags are nicely done thanks to the HubFlow automated tool.

Question is, what should I do if I now want to bump the version up to 0.0.1 on my master branch proper?

Is it

a) create another release branch using the command

```
git hf release start 0.0.1
```

bump up the version

```
git commit -a -m 'Bump to 0.0.1'
```

then finish the release

```
git hf release end 0.0.1
```

**OR**

b) go to master branch

```
git checkout master
```

and bump up the version

```
git commit -a -m 'Bump to 0.0.1'
```

**OR**

c) something else?

Thank you.